# Ansible subtasks with dynamic hosts

Tags: ansible, hosts, nokia

I have a dictionary with hostnames.
To every hostname I would like to connect via SSH and to some tasks.

I tried something like this, but this does not work.
Any tips and tricks how to achieve this.

**main.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: network_cli
  vars:
    - input: "{{ lookup('file','temp/yoda-xxx-xx.json') | from_json }}"
    - ansible_network_os: nokia.sros.classic
    - ansible_ssh_user: user
    - ansible_password: password
  tasks:
    - name: Configure Main
      - include_tasks: worker.yml
        with_items: "{{ input.delta_config }}"
```

**worker.yml**

```
---
- hosts: "{{ item.device }}"
  gather_facts: No
  connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: Configure 
      community.network.sros_config:
        src: "temp/{{ item.device }}"
        save: yes
        match: line
```

**JSON Input**

```
{
   "device":"yoda-xxx-xx",
   "config_file":"C:\yoda-xxx-xx.cfg",
   "delta_config":[
      {
         "device":"yoda-yy-01",
         "config_file":"temp/yoda-xxx-xx_delta_for_yoda-yy-01.txt"
      },
      {
         "device":"yoda-yy-02",
         "config_file":"temp/yoda-xxx-xx_delta_for_yoda-yy-02.txt"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @burg and welcome to SO. Please provide an example of the json file.

Comment: You have several problems.  The `task` line is not indented.  You are trying to include an entire playbook with `include_tasks`.  And if you are parsing a JSON file to get hosts, parse the JSON file with a shell script and use that shell script as the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `include_tasks` a playbook. `include_tasks` is used to include a tasklist (a list of tasks without `hosts: ...` and `tasks:` statements).

If you want to use dynamic hosts, use `add_host` module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html

Alternatively, you may write a proper inventory snippet into a directory with a current inventory (you need to turn your inventory into a directory for that) and to do `meta: refresh_inventory` call to see new hosts.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I changed it now to one playbook with the `add_hosts` Option.
But now my config will be done always for both hosts.

Comment: Found a solution with the `when` statement. Thanks a lot for your help!